# Elasticsearch node keeps restarting

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a simple 3 node cluster here at home used for testing. 3 eligible master nodes and two data nodes. However, one of the two data nodes can never seem to initialize the data shards properly.

The cluster health and shards overview illustrate this.

```
{"cluster_name":"test","status":"yellow","timed_out":false,"number_of_nodes":3,"number_of_data_nodes":2,"active_primary_shards":28,"active_shards":50,"relocating_shards":0,"initializing_shards":2,"unassigned_shards":4,"number_of_pending_tasks":0}
```

The shards overview indicate that the various shards are being initialized

```
.marvel-2015.05.28 0 r INITIALIZING              127.0.0.1 ES2 
.marvel-2015.05.28 0 p STARTED      7656  21.3mb 127.0.0.1 ES1 
.kibana            0 r STARTED                   127.0.0.1 ES2 
.kibana            0 p STARTED        16  13.8kb 127.0.0.1 ES1 
kibana-int         4 p STARTED         0    115b 127.0.0.1 ES1 
kibana-int         2 r INITIALIZING              127.0.0.1 ES2
```

However, at some point during this process, the node just dies and restarts.

```
{"cluster_name":"olympus","status":"yellow","timed_out":false,"number_of_nodes":2,"number_of_data_nodes":1,"active_primary_shards":28,"active_shards":28,"relocating_shards":0,"initializing_shards":0,"unassigned_shards":28,"number_of_pending_tasks":0}
```

The node eventually comes back up and the aforementioned process starts up again, but then it just dies eventually yet again.

The logs on the problematic node doesnt seem to say much either.

```
[2015-05-28 11:31:38,984][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [ES2] detected_master [ES1][mZUzucXKTnGUdfXNx1OYEQ][es1][inet[/192.168.88.22:9300]], added {[ES3][onaC5Y2bSd-nVTDRXsxjBg][es3pi][inet[/192.168.88.21:9300]]{data=false, master=true},[ES1][mZUzucXKTnGUdfXNx1OYEQ][es1][inet[/192.168.88.22:9300]],}, reason: zen-disco-receive(from master [[ES1][mZUzucXKTnGUdfXNx1OYEQ][es1][inet[/192.168.88.22:9300]]])
[2015-05-28 11:31:40,717][INFO ][http                     ] [ES2] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9200]}, publish_address {inet[/192.168.88.20:9200]}
[2015-05-28 11:31:40,722][INFO ][node                     ] [ES2] started
[2015-05-28 11:34:21,024][INFO ][node                     ] [ES2] version[1.5.2], pid[591], build[62ff986/2015-04-27T09:21:06Z]
[2015-05-28 11:34:21,065][INFO ][node                     ] [ES2] initializing ...
[2015-05-28 11:34:21,826][INFO ][plugins                  ] [ES2] loaded [marvel], sites [marvel]
[2015-05-28 11:35:41,387][INFO ][node                     ] [ES2] initialized
[2015-05-28 11:35:41,401][INFO ][node                     ] [ES2] starting ...
[2015-05-28 11:35:43,174][INFO ][transport                ] [ES2] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9300]}, publish_address {inet[/192.168.88.20:9300]}
[2015-05-28 11:35:43,538][INFO ][discovery                ] [ES2] olympus/FQWotgreS2iTZ_NAJEBmaA
[2015-05-28 11:35:47,758][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [ES2] detected_master [ES1][mZUzucXKTnGUdfXNx1OYEQ][es1][inet[/192.168.88.22:9300]], added {[ES3][onaC5Y2bSd-nVTDRXsxjBg][es3pi][inet[/192.168.88.21:9300]]{data=false, master=true},[ES1][mZUzucXKTnGUdfXNx1OYEQ][es1][inet[/192.168.88.22:9300]],}, reason: zen-disco-receive(from master [[ES1][mZUzucXKTnGUdfXNx1OYEQ][es1][inet[/192.168.88.22:9300]]])
[2015-05-28 11:35:49,442][INFO ][http                     ] [ES2] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9200]}, publish_address {inet[/192.168.88.20:9200]}
[2015-05-28 11:35:49,447][INFO ][node                     ] [ES2] started
[2015-05-28 11:39:40,064][INFO ][node                     ] [ES2] version[1.5.2], pid[655], build[62ff986/2015-04-27T09:21:06Z]
[2015-05-28 11:39:40,088][INFO ][node                     ] [ES2] initializing ...
[2015-05-28 11:39:40,880][INFO ][plugins                  ] [ES2] loaded [marvel], sites [marvel]
[2015-05-28 11:41:03,892][INFO ][node                     ] [ES2] initialized
[2015-05-28 11:41:03,906][INFO ][node                     ] [ES2] starting ...
[2015-05-28 11:41:05,665][INFO ][transport                ] [ES2] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9300]}, publish_address {inet[/192.168.88.20:9300]}
[2015-05-28 11:41:06,042][INFO ][discovery                ] [ES2] olympus/5JH1JO7PRICesi0tadHZJw
[2015-05-28 11:41:10,233][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [ES2] detected_master [ES1][mZUzucXKTnGUdfXNx1OYEQ][es1][inet[/192.168.88.22:9300]], added {[ES3][onaC5Y2bSd-nVTDRXsxjBg][es3pi][inet[/192.168.88.21:9300]]{data=false, master=true},[ES1][mZUzucXKTnGUdfXNx1OYEQ][es1][inet[/192.168.88.22:9300]],}, reason: zen-disco-receive(from master [[ES1][mZUzucXKTnGUdfXNx1OYEQ][es1][inet[/192.168.88.22:9300]]])
[2015-05-28 11:41:11,844][INFO ][http                     ] [ES2] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9200]}, publish_address {inet[/192.168.88.20:9200]}
[2015-05-28 11:41:11,850][INFO ][node                     ] [ES2] started
[2015-05-28 11:44:47,113][INFO ][node                     ] [ES2] version[1.5.2], pid[763], build[62ff986/2015-04-27T09:21:06Z]
[2015-05-28 11:44:47,173][INFO ][node                     ] [ES2] initializing ...
[2015-05-28 11:44:47,985][INFO ][plugins                  ] [ES2] loaded [marvel], sites [marvel]
[2015-05-28 11:46:08,003][INFO ][node                     ] [ES2] initialized
[2015-05-28 11:46:08,017][INFO ][node                     ] [ES2] starting ...
[2015-05-28 11:46:09,818][INFO ][transport                ] [ES2] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9300]}, publish_address {inet[/192.168.88.20:9300]}
[2015-05-28 11:46:10,184][INFO ][discovery                ] [ES2] olympus/AjDpUJt1SK2ncVah2ZVQJA
[2015-05-28 11:46:14,397][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [ES2] detected_master [ES1][mZUzucXKTnGUdfXNx1OYEQ][es1][inet[/192.168.88.22:9300]], added {[ES3][onaC5Y2bSd-nVTDRXsxjBg][es3pi][inet[/192.168.88.21:9300]]{data=false, master=true},[ES1][mZUzucXKTnGUdfXNx1OYEQ][es1][inet[/192.168.88.22:9300]],}, reason: zen-disco-receive(from master [[ES1][mZUzucXKTnGUdfXNx1OYEQ][es1][inet[/192.168.88.22:9300]]])
[2015-05-28 11:46:16,056][INFO ][http                     ] [ES2] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9200]}, publish_address {inet[/192.168.88.20:9200]}
[2015-05-28 11:46:16,061][INFO ][node                     ] [ES2] started
[2015-05-28 11:49:49,595][INFO ][node                     ] [ES2] version[1.5.2], pid[824], build[62ff986/2015-04-27T09:21:06Z]
[2015-05-28 11:49:49,628][INFO ][node                     ] [ES2] initializing ...
[2015-05-28 11:49:50,394][INFO ][plugins                  ] [ES2] loaded [marvel], sites [marvel]
[2015-05-28 11:51:17,611][INFO ][node                     ] [ES2] initialized
[2015-05-28 11:51:17,626][INFO ][node                     ] [ES2] starting ...
[2015-05-28 11:51:19,409][INFO ][transport                ] [ES2] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9300]}, publish_address {inet[/192.168.88.20:9300]}
[2015-05-28 11:51:19,775][INFO ][discovery                ] [ES2] olympus/KVeatmVAR4aGzumHUy4PQA
[2015-05-28 11:51:24,007][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [ES2] detected_master [ES1][mZUzucXKTnGUdfXNx1OYEQ][es1][inet[/192.168.88.22:9300]], added {[ES3][onaC5Y2bSd-nVTDRXsxjBg][es3pi][inet[/192.168.88.21:9300]]{data=false, master=true},[ES1][mZUzucXKTnGUdfXNx1OYEQ][es1][inet[/192.168.88.22:9300]],}, reason: zen-disco-receive(from master [[ES1][mZUzucXKTnGUdfXNx1OYEQ][es1][inet[/192.168.88.22:9300]]])
[2015-05-28 11:51:25,739][INFO ][http                     ] [ES2] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9200]}, publish_address {inet[/192.168.88.20:9200]}
[2015-05-28 11:51:25,744][INFO ][node                     ] [ES2] started
[2015-05-28 11:55:05,150][INFO ][node                     ] [ES2] version[1.5.2], pid[933], build[62ff986/2015-04-27T09:21:06Z]
[2015-05-28 11:55:05,157][INFO ][node                     ] [ES2] initializing ...
[2015-05-28 11:55:06,032][INFO ][plugins                  ] [ES2] loaded [marvel], sites [marvel]
[2015-05-28 11:56:24,370][INFO ][node                     ] [ES2] initialized
[2015-05-28 11:56:24,384][INFO ][node                     ] [ES2] starting ...
[2015-05-28 11:56:26,136][INFO ][transport                ] [ES2] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9300]}, publish_address {inet[/192.168.88.20:9300]}
[2015-05-28 11:56:26,496][INFO ][discovery                ] [ES2] olympus/DVO0kHFbQf66qX95DHfzjw
[2015-05-28 11:56:30,717][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [ES2] detected_master [ES1][mZUzucXKTnGUdfXNx1OYEQ][es1][inet[/192.168.88.22:9300]], added {[ES3][onaC5Y2bSd-nVTDRXsxjBg][es3pi][inet[/192.168.88.21:9300]]{data=false, master=true},[ES1][mZUzucXKTnGUdfXNx1OYEQ][es1][inet[/192.168.88.22:9300]],}, reason: zen-disco-receive(from master [[ES1][mZUzucXKTnGUdfXNx1OYEQ][es1][inet[/192.168.88.22:9300]]])
[2015-05-28 11:56:32,396][INFO ][http                     ] [ES2] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9200]}, publish_address {inet[/192.168.88.20:9200]}
[2015-05-28 11:56:32,410][INFO ][node                     ] [ES2] started
```

Anyone have any ideas on what's going wrong here? It would be much appreciated!

Comment: Probably, something's (kernel panic) killing your node. Is the OS running out of memory? :-)

Comment: Actually, this might be the case. The node (a raspberry pi) is seemingly running very low on available memory before it dies. However, the OS itself is running fine, its apparently just the elasticsearch process that restarts. However, there is a sizable swap partition in use which is not being touched for some reason.

Comment: The OS will run fine if it kills the process that's creating troubles ;-).

Comment: What if you split your powerful VM into two smaller nodes and leave the PIs to handle the master node role?

Comment: That would probably work, however, data redundancy spread across two VM's on the same physical server doesnt really make much sense. Then again, using the Raspberry Pi's for it doesnt either. That said, maybe Ill get a Raspberry PI 2 with 1GB of RAM. At any rate, thanks for pointing me in the right direction.